# python __lt__ __gt__ custom (overloaded) operators

Tags: python, overloading, operator-keyword

Having experimented with Python, I've come to the code:

```
class Chainable(object):
    value = []
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.value = []
        for a in args:
            if isinstance(a,list):
                self.value += a
            elif isinstance(a,tuple):
                self.value += list(a)
            else: 
                self.value += [a]
        return 

    def __lt__(self,a):
        self.value = [a]+self.value
        return self
    def __gt__(self,a):
        self.value = self.value+[a]
        return self
    def __or__(self,x):
        self.value += [x]
        return self
```

When I run code like this:

```
a = Chainable(1,2,3)
```

I can ask: `a | 4 | 5` and receive result as `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

But when I ask for `a > 4 > 5` all I get is `False` and `a` = `[1,2,3,4]`.

Could you help pointing to the table of operator ordering or so?

Comment: `a > 4 > 5` is `a > 4 and 4 > 5`, and `4` is clearly smaller than `5`. What answer were you expecting? See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in

Comment: The result is understandable, but the same code with | works.

Comment: ...yes? `|` is not a comparison operator, so doesn't invoke the chaining, but `>` is.

Comment: Then the answer is that comparison operators (<,>,==, etc) evaluates differently - and not left-to-right order

Comment: It's not just *"left-to-right order"* for the other operators, either; there are also [precedence rules](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: And with `((a > 4) > 5)` I'm getting right result.

Comment: Thank you! I've missed this part of documentation!

Comment: Again... yes? Parentheses come first, as they do in precedence rules in most languages. I wouldn't call `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` the *"right result"* - surely the larger problem here is that you've defined `__lt__` and `__gt__` in a profoundly counterintuitive way? They would normally (see e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) return `True` or `False`.

Comment: The reason of letting this counter-intuitive way was an experiment of domain-specific language in Python.

This part was for managing a queue (push to the front and back).

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but using the comparison operators to define your own syntax is only going to confuse other people trying to use your code. Maybe stick to the shift operators `<<` and `>>`, which behave closer to the way you expect?

Comment: Yes, using << and >> would be a way better solution!

Answer (score 0):

The resulting solution (thanks to [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)):

```
class Chainable(object):
    value = []
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.value = []
        for a in args:
            if isinstance(a,list):
                self.value += a
            elif isinstance(a,tuple):
                self.value += list(a)
            else: 
                self.value += [a]
        return 

    def __lshift__(self,a):
        self.value = [a]+self.value
        return self
    def __rshift__(self,a):
        self.value = self.value+[a]
        return self
    def __or__(self,x):
        self.value += [x]
        return self
```

and an operation would be like this:

```
a = Chainable(1,2,3)
a << 0 << -1 >> 4 >> 5
[-1,0,1,2,3,4,5]
```